# Software That Create Alter Edit Web Requests to A Site

Tags: webrequest

I need a software that acts as a web browser and also gives user the ability to examine web requests and reponses, also change/alter/edit them.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

## Fiddler software

Use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/).  Which can let you monitor all web traffic on your machine and tamper with the client requests and responses.

## Or your favorite web browser can do this for you.

In any browser you can press <kbd>F12</kbd> to bring up an inspection window, then go to the Network tab to see the requests being made.

If you want to alter them, you can use an extension like [Request Maker for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/request-maker/kajfghlhfkcocafkcjlajldicbikpgnp?hl=en) or [Modify Headers for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/modify-headers/).